# How can I properly secure these tarps?

Tags: repair, garage

I'm in the process of building my home and need some way to temporarily cover the garage door openings. I purchased a couple of tarps and secured them from the inside using some #10 ½" wood screws. This didn't stay up long due to the winds. I also tried securing the tarps using the built-in rings, but those also got ripped off.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you need to be able to enter and exit regularly through these openings or will they be sealed until the permanent doors are installed?

Comment: And what is the size of the openings?

Comment: @bib Sealed until permanent doors are installed. Small opening is 9'x8' and large opening is 16'x8'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap the edges of the tarp around a 1x2 and then screw through the 1x2 and into the garage frame. The more times you can wrap, the better.

[image]

EDIT - just saw the last photo. You could screw a 1x2 against the side of the stud that the tarp is currently wrapping around.

Comment: This has been working well so far. The area is expecting wind gusts up to 50 mph. I'll update how well it holds.

Comment: That's pretty fierce, the answers that included some sort of back up studs or sheet might serve you well. But I suppose you'll find out!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install temporary studs to wall off the openings.  Secure the tarps by trapping the material between the studs and some lath strips.  (Of course you'll discard the tarps afterward because they'll be full of holes.)

You might also consider leaving the middle third of the foot of the tarp unattached, to vent the strongest gusts before they blow out the material.

Answer (score 0):

If these ports are not going to be used, I would put up temporary framing (2x3 or 2x4) and attach cheap 1/2" plywood. If a seal is needed, use duct tape.

In a pinch, you could rig a shop door, about 30x96, on strap hinges to give access.

While this may be slightly more expensive than tarps, it gives you security against both weather and intrusion.